# FFmpeg add complex filter image and audio to video

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm working with `fluent-ffmpeg` for Node and would like to add a `gif` image and an `audio` to an mp4 video. The gif added with `complexFilter` works as expected, but the audio does not work with the `complexFilter` applied. Without the `complexFilter`, the audio works as expected.

```
    ffmpeg('/Users/xxx/functions/src/initialvideo.mp4')
    .setFfmpegPath(ffmpeg_static.path)
    .input('/Users/xxx/functions/src/somegif.gif')
    .complexFilter(
      [
        {
          "filter": "overlay",
          "options": {
            "enable": "between(t,0,4)",
            "x": "810",
            "y": "465"
          },
          "inputs": "[0:v][1:v]",
          "outputs": "tmp"
        }

      ], ['tmp'])
    .addInput('/Users/xxx/functions/src/somemusic.mp3')

    .outputOptions(['-pix_fmt yuv420p'])
   .on('end',() => {

     return response.status(200).send(`Error getting collection: `)

  })
   .on('error',() => {
     return response.status(500).send(`Internal Server Error: `)

   })
   .save('/Users/xxx/functions/src/finalvideo.mp4')
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

Comment: Have you tried moving the complexFilter after the `input` with the music file?